# Looking for the best way to store files between two web applications running on docker

Tags: file, docker, server, architecture, symfony4

we have two symfony 4 application (web app & rest api) running on two different docker container on the same "real" server (for now).

The files (like picture or documents) are stored in the web app public directory for the moment but we want to share this files to the rest api as well.

What is the best way to share them ?

Store them on the docker parent server ? Build a new web server for this files and access them by sftp ?

We want to have all access (by the two app) on the new file system, like make directory, put files, delete files and directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you're using 1 docker container for web app + 1 container for rest api. To store files (images, documents ...) on web app public directory is not a good solution.
If you decide to have more replicas (more containers) of web app you'll have trouble.

One solution will be to have a service where to store all you're application files and use it by all your app containers.
You can you [Minio Server for Docker](https://www.minio.io/docker.html) to create this service and in your symfony application use that minio server service for all your application instances. See here an example >> [How to use AWS SDK for PHP with Minio Server](https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-php-with-minio-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use a distributed file system such as GlusterFS, that should fit your needs.
All container can have the shared volume write and read from it. And also it works great on swarm.